# How to do this in HTML and CSS?

Tags: css, html

I have a situation where the Image or Icon is in a LEFT-FLOATING  and the Details too in the LEFT-FLOATING

The Problem is the Shadowed- DIV is not wrapping around the content.

How to do this?

[image: Screenshot: Problem]

Edit the Structure of the HTML is :

```
<div "shadowed one"> // no overflow: auto; but it doesn't have any effect +/- overflow
  <div "+/- overflow: auto">
   <div "floating left">Icon</div>
   <div "floating left">Details</div
  <div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `clear: both` to clear the floats (just add an extra element in the container with that style)

Comment: I don't think it is a clearing problem, since when `overflow: auto` is set the content is being cut off.

Comment: I don't think it is reasonable to ask the stackoverflow community to fix code they do not have access to.

Comment: do your internal divs have a width and height, or a min-width and min-height? Is the problem browser specific?  This would be a lot easier to solve if we could see your actual code.

Comment: No the LEFT-FLOATING divs are not set with any height. As are the outer container.

Comment: Okay, I recreated your situation in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VauBY/1/ . Now as you can see, both floating div's (background colour red and yellow) are coming over de border. The trick here is to add `overflow: hidden;` to your *wrapping* div, as you can see in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VauBY/2/ . Yes, it is this simple...

Comment: Funny this question is closed, though the question is pretty clear to me (and anyone who has ever experienced this "problem").

Comment: @Styxxy You could have written it as Answer. And I would've marked it such. Anyway Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Styxxy, notice how it was closed 4 minutes _before_ any code was included.

Comment: @TheBlackSandal The answer was closed for a minute when I tried to post the answer.

Comment: @Sparky672 True, but the post with the image already said quite a lot about the problem ;).

Comment: @Styxxy, the third comment above by Quentin is a good explanation.  And this is not the place to debate/discuss.  If you want to ask about why certain questions are closed, please take it over to http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample for you on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/uqSGM/).

Rather than float both divisions, float the image and add a margin to the description.

Comment: This doesn't work when the image (on the left) is higher than the description (on the right).

Comment: That doesn't work either. It still produces the result two.

Comment: Styxxy - if you were filing this as a bug report, I know you'd include more detail. Florent - that isn't the requirement if you look at the question. The Black Sandal - not on the JS Fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

try changing the height and padding of the shaddowed div

if its already a set height it wont magically fit around the content

Comment: There is no height set in the shadowed div dude.

Comment: ok if every entry you do is like that "Harry Potter Series" figure out a height that works and fits around it.

Comment: That doesn't work either. But you see there are different products with different amount of details and descriptions. So something might come even after the BUY NOW button.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the [*clearfix*](http://themergency.com/css-clearfix-demystified/) trick or the CSS property `clear: both`

Example with clearfix:

```
<!-- Clearfix on the parent div -->
<div class="shadowed one clearfix">
    <!-- Floating divs with different height -->
    <div class="floating left">Icon</div>
    <div class="floating left">Details</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Every body is saying to use clearfix or Clear: Both. But where to use it? in the first or second div?